# When on full screen back,forward,refresh,home buttons on Chrome do not work

Tags: 22.04, google-chrome, bug-reporting

As the title says... but using the F5 key I can refresh the page and in general Chrome (not to be confused with chromium) is responsive I can open new tabs open a bookmark or the settings or click on existing tabs etc..

Also I can click on the back forward etc buttons but only if NOT on full screen.. :/

My kernel 6.1.4-x64v3-xanmod1
My OS: Ubunt 22.04 LTS

My installed package list https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8Ckx2JTPZG/

Comment: If you right click in a blank space it will tell you what key commands you can press to navigate back or forwards.  You can also select them from the menu that pops up.  If not, you might have found a bug, but you will have to file it with Google since Ubuntu (Canonical) does not do any coding for Chrome.

Comment: yea it works like that but it doesnt solve the issue I mean if I just shrink the window a little but then the buttons work again without issue. I made a bug report to google about it but I am not sure if the bug is on their side maybe its ubuntu/wayland related

Comment: Well, it is a bug, but not with Ubuntu.  The full screen issue happens with different distros of Linux where if you press the F11 key you cannot activate the tabs or the back and forward buttons.  It is kind of sad because it would be nice to have the tabs and the buttons popup if you mouse to the top of the screen like it does on the Mac OS.  Unfortunately, filing a bug with Google is the only thing that can be done.

Comment: @Terrance I did fill a bug with google but I am pretty sure it is a gnome/x11 thing because only a SECTION of pixels (top left) doesnt work when on full screen (hence everything works fine when not in full screen and not overlay the window so that the back button etc gets on that top left section of pixels) furthermore if an other app is behind chrome (while chrome on full screen) and I click back the other app (which is invisible and behind the chrome window) e.g steam gets clicked on that exact point where the back button is visible to me

Comment: OK, when you are saying full screen, you mean pressing F11, right?  There is a difference between Maximize and Full Screen.  Full Screen will never allow you to click anything behind the open application.

Comment: I meant maximize

Answer (score 0):

Searching for this issue I first thought this did not apply to me as I don't consider my 2 apps, side by side, on my wide screen monitor to be maximized. Plus, I am not using Chrome. But when it started happening in Brave, on Ubuntu 23.04, I finally gave up and uninstalled it and switched to Vivaldi. SAME thing. From reading this post, I went to the top of the browser window and slid it down about 1" from the top of the screen and suddenly the back button (as well as the others to the left of the address bar) started working. This must be an issue in Ubuntu as even Brave does not do this on my Windows 11 laptop.